# last value in sqlite column with aiosqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, python-asyncio

Could anyone give me a tip with asyncio SQLite on how to retrieve the last value from a column named `kW`? Only column in the db named `save_data` with one table named `all_data.`

In SQLite db browser if I run `SELECT * FROM all_data ORDER BY kW DESC LIMIT 1;` this will return:
`2021-02-01 09:23:09.758140 73.7699966430664`

Which is correct but includes the timestamp but I am only interested in the value `73.7699966430664`

Any tips help not an expert on sql and trying to learn asyncio at the same time. The code below doesn't require asyncio but its part of something else I am working on...

```
import asyncio
import aiosqlite


async def collect_report_value():
    async with aiosqlite.connect("./save_data.db") as conn:
        result = await conn.execute("SELECT * FROM all_data ORDER BY kW DESC LIMIT 1;")
        print(result)
        return result

asyncio.run(collect_report_value())
```

This just prints `<aiosqlite.cursor.Cursor object at 0x000001EEFCF9A808>`

Any tips on how to retrieve data value from sql (not the timestamp) through asyncio methods greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried only selecting the column you need, instead of all columns in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to fetch your object:

```
result = await conn.execute("select kw from all_data order by kw desc limit 1")
resultfetch = await result.fetchone()
print(resultfetch[0])
```

and the sql related you can make it simplier by requesting only the desired column:

```
select kw from all_data order by kw desc limit 1;
```

I have assumed you want the kw column, but I my have misunderstood your question, it you meant another column, just replace it in the select statement.

Comment: If I run `select kw from all_data order by kw desc limit 1;` that looks good in the db browser. Thank you. But if I run the code with the `print(result.fetchone()[0])` I get an asyncio error `TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Any ideas to try :)

Comment: i have edited the anwser with one extra async/await step, see if it works